# Robot Return to Origin

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

**The task**
is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/robot-return-to-origin/)

> There is a robot starting at position (0, 0), the origin, on a 2D
>   plane. Given a sequence of its moves, judge if this robot ends up at
>   (0, 0) after it completes its moves.
>
> The move sequence is represented by a string, and the character
>   moves[i] represents its ith move. Valid moves are R (right), L (left),
>   U (up), and D (down). If the robot returns to the origin after it
>   finishes all of its moves, return true. Otherwise, return false.
>
> Note: The way that the robot is "facing" is irrelevant. "R" will
>   always make the robot move to the right once, "L" will always make it
>   move left, etc. Also, assume that the magnitude of the robot's
>   movement is the same for each move.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: "UD" Output: true  Explanation: The robot moves up once, and
>   then down once. All moves have the same magnitude, so it ended up at
>   the origin where it started. Therefore, we return true.
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: "LL" Output: false Explanation: The robot moves left twice. It
>   ends up two "moves" to the left of the origin. We return false because
>   it is not at the origin at the end of its moves.

```
const arr = "UD";
```

**My imperative solution:**

```
function judgeCircle(moves) {
  let horizontal = 0;
  let vertical = 0;

  [...moves].forEach(m => {
    switch(m) {
      case "U":
        ++vertical;
        break;
      case "D":
        --vertical;
        break;
      case "R":
        ++horizontal;
        break;
      case "L":
        --horizontal;
        break;
      default:
        // be a good code
    }
  });
  return !(horizontal) && !(vertical);
};

console.log(judgeCircle(arr));
```

**My functional solution:**

```
const judgeCircle2 = moves => {
  const {h, v} = [...moves].reduce((acc,m) => {
    switch(m) {
      case "U":
        ++acc.v;
        return acc;
      case "D":
        --acc.v;
        return acc;
      case "R":
        ++acc.h;
        return acc;
      case "L":
        --acc.h;
        return acc;
      default:
        // be a good code
    }
  }, {h: 0, v: 0});
  return !h && !v;
};

console.log(judgeCircle2(arr));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often replace `switch` statements with lookup functions. For example

```
function returnsHome(moves) {
    var v = 0, h = 0;
    const dirs = { 
        U() {v++}, 
        D() {v--}, 
        L() {h--}, 
        R() {h++} 
    };
    for (const move of moves) { dirs[move]() }
    return !(h || v);
}

// or
function returnsHome(moves) {
    var v = 0, h = 0;
    const dirs = {U() {v++}, D() {v--}, L() {h--}, R() {h++}};
    for (const m of moves) { dirs[m]() }
    return !(h || v);
}
```

There is also a very quick way to workout if the result is false by checking if the number of moves is odd.

```
function returnsHome(moves) {
    var v = 0, h = 0;
    if (moves.length % 2) { return false }        
    const dirs = {U() {v++}, D() {v--}, L() {h--}, R() {h++}};
    for (const m of moves) { dirs[m]() }
    return !(h || v);
}
```

Another early exit can be found if a particular distance moved if greater than the remaining number of moves.

```
function returnsHome(moves) {
    var v = 0, h = 0, remainingSteps = moves.length;
    if (remainingSteps % 2) { return false }
    const dirs = {U() {v++}, D() {v--}, L() {h--}, R() {h++}};
    for (const m of moves) { 
        dirs[m]();
        if (--remainingSteps < (Math.abs(v) + Math.abs(h))) {  return false }
    }
    return !(h || v);
}
```

UPDATE I got that wrong, it does not work for all cases

<strike>Finally you could also use `String.replace` to solve</strike>

```
function returnsHome(m) {
    const rep = dir => (m = m.replace(dir, "")).length;
    return !(
        m.length % 2 || (m.length - rep(/D/g)) - (m.length - rep(/U/g)) || 
        m.length % 2 || rep(/L/g) - m.length
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be made more functional by avoiding the mutation of `acc`. The effects are contained within `judgeCircle` so it's not a big deal, but it feels like if you're going to mutate the accumulator, you might as well just use an imperative loop.

I also preferred to be explicit about the final check. I find the intent of `!h && !v` isn't quite as clear as `h == 0 && v == 0;`.

I ended up with:

```
const judgeCircle3 = moves => {
  const [hori, vert] = [...moves].reduce(([h, v], move) => {
    switch(move) {
      case "U":
        return [h, v + 1];

      case "D":
        return [h, v - 1];

      case "R":
        return [h + 1, v];

      case "L":
        return [h - 1, v];
    }

  }, [0, 0]);

  return hori == 0 && vert == 0;
};
```

The need for the `switch` here is unfortunate, but the only other alternative I could think of was some mess where a you'd do a lookup on a map which returned a function that returned a "altered" accumulator state.

I also got rid of the `default` since it didn't seem to be doing anything. You could have done error handling in there (and should in most cases), but if it's a challenge with predefined input, that's probably not necessary unless it's part of the challenge.

Comment: Good point with avoiding the `acc`. I'll keep this in mind for future tasks.